# Selenium button click not resulting in next page

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been researching this issue for the better part of a day.  I have looked at multiple StackOverflow postings as well as off-site postings.

My problem appears to be different in that the click or submit doesn't error, the button is visible, but clicking doesn't result in the expected page to be loaded with the desired results.

As you can see from the commented sections below, I have tried several ways to get a result from the click/submit.

Any help is appreciated

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class HeadlessChrome {

    // private static final String STREET_NUMBER = "ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtStreetNumber";
    // private static final String STREET_NAME = "ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreet";
    // private static final String CITY = "ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtCity";
    // public static final String SEARCH_BUTTON = "ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$btnSearch";
    //
    // public static final String RESULTS_PANEL = "ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_pnlResults";

    @Test
    public void createChromeDriverHeadless() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Volumes/Lagoon/Users/heiden/Documents/Java/chromedriver");

        final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

        final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

        driver.navigate().to("http://www.dupageco.org/PropertyInfo/PropertyLookup.aspx");

        final WebDriverWait waitForWebsite = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        waitForWebsite.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                .name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreetNumber")));

        final Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreetNumber")));
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys("1202");

        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreet")));
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys("Willow");

        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtCity")));
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys("Wheaton");


        final WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$btnSearch"));
        // actions.moveToElement(searchButton);
        // actions.click();

        actions.build().perform();

        // final JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        // jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + searchButton.getLocation().y + ")");

        searchButton.submit();

        final WebDriverWait waitForResponse = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        waitForResponse.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                .name("ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_pnlResults")));
        //
        // driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_pnlResults"));

        final String expectedURL = "http://www.dupageco.org/PropertyInformation.aspx";
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedURL, driver.getCurrentUrl());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

BTW, the static class variables weren't used directly because the By.name wouldn't complete in my test unless I used the string directly in the method argument.  That is the weirdest thing I have ever seen.

Thanks

Update (A portion of the HTML, hopefully the useful portion):

```
// --></script><div id="Mai

n" name="Main" title="Main" onblur="design_validate_re(/\S+/,this,'Cannot be blank');" xmlns:cms="urn:Ektron.Cms.Controls"><h1>Property Lookup</h1><p>This portal leads to the following information for a parcel:</p><ul><li>Tax bill information plus the ability to <strong>pay current year tax bill </strong>and print a duplicate tax bill.</li><li>Tax distribution information - where do your tax dollars go?  Includes links to the taxing bodies.</li><li>Assessment information, including any reviews or corrections made to assessments.  PLEASE NOTE:  The Township Assessors publish property characteristics and assessment data on          
        <a title="their websites" href="/SOA/1488/">the Assessor websites</a>.</li></ul><p><strong>Parcels can be searched using either parcel number (PIN = Property Index Number) or address.</strong></p><p><span class="warning"></span><a title="View the tax payment calendar" href="/Treasurer/5943/">View the tax payment calendar</a>.     </p></div>


            <span id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_errMsg" CssStyle="warning"></span>
<div id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_pnlSearch" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_btnSearch&#39;)">

    <div style="border:solid 1px black;padding-left:10px;margin:5px">
        <h2>Search by PIN</h2>
        <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtParcel" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblParcel">PIN: </label>
        <input name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtParcel" type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtParcel" style="width:70px;" /><br />
        <span class="warning">Leave off hyphens.</span>
    </div><span class="larger"></span>
    <div style="text-align:center; color:#29547E"><strong>&mdash; OR &mdash;</strong></div>
    <div style="border:solid 1px black;padding-left:10px;margin:5px">
        <h2>Search by Address</h2>
         <p><strong>To return more results, enter partial street numbers, street names, or cities.  Optional fields can also be left blank.</strong>
        <br />Examples:  '10' instead of '1001', 'Roo' instead of 'Roosevelt', 'Glen' instead of 'Glendale Hts' or 'Glen Ellyn'.</p><br />
        <ul class="PropLookupul">
            <li>
                <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtStreetNumber" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblStreetNumber" class="PropLookuplbl">Street Number: </label>
                <input name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreetNumber" type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtStreetNumber" style="width:70px;" /><strong> * Required</strong>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_ddlDir" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblDir" class="PropLookuplbl">Direction: </label>
                <select name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$ddlDir" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_ddlDir">
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="N">N</option>
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="W">W</option>

    </select> Optional
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtStreet" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblStreet" class="PropLookuplbl">Street: </label>
                <input name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreet" type="text" maxlength="22" size="22" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtStreet" style="width:150px;" /><strong> * Required</strong><br />
                <span class="warning">Leave off street designations like 'st', 'street', etc.</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtNumber" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblNumber" class="PropLookuplbl">Unit: </label>
                <input name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtNumber" type="text" maxlength="14" size="14" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtNumber" style="width:150px;" /> Optional
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtCity" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_lblCity" class="PropLookuplbl">City: </label>
                <input name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtCity" type="text" maxlength="30" size="30" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_txtCity" style="width:150px;" /> Optional
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>


<div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$btnSearch" value="Search" id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_btnSearch" class="btn" />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value=" Clear " onclick="window.location='/PropertyInfo/PropertyLookUp.aspx';return false;" />
</div>



<div id="ctl00_pageContent_ctl00_ContentFooter">
    <span style="display:none" xmlns:cms="urn:Ektron.Cms.Controls"> </span><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" defer="defer" xmlns:cms="urn:Ektron.Cms.Controls"><!--
function ektLocalizeDate(date, id) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.getElementById && 10 == date.length) {
        var oTempDate = new Date(date.substr(0,4), parseInt(date.substr(5,2),10)-1, date.substr(8,2));
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=(oTempDate.toLocaleDateString ? oTempDate.toLocaleDateString() : oTempDate.toLocaleString());
    }
    }, 1); 
}
```

Comment: Which button are you trying to click? Can you share the `HTML` from the `DOM`? I don't see you invoking the powerful Java `click()`

Comment: I am trying to use the submit button.  I tried click to start with, though it didn't survive into comments.  I didn't include the HTML to keep the post short, choosing to supply the URL instead.  If it is still needed/wanted by others, I will edit in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons are:

1. There are several elements which are matched to your xpath. So when you click, you only click to the first element which do not have redirect to next page.
2. You use incorrect element, because redirect link or onClick event can exist on another element. So play around with nearest elements. Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
3. If nothing helps, try this one:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", button);`

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I have positively identified the submit button by both name and id, so I'm certain I am using the correct element.  I tried the javascript you provided also without success.  I will continue to return looking for a solution.  I appreciate your insights and will keep them for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

The below code running fine to me in firefox

```
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreetNumber")).sendKeys("1202");
        driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtStreet")).sendKeys("Willow");
        driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$txtCity")).sendKeys("Wheaton");
        driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$pageContent$ctl00$btnSearch")).click();
```